# Service receives commands after Thread.sleep

Tags: java, android

I have the following simple code:

**Activity**

```
private void myStartService(String action) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    intent.setAction(action);
    startService(intent);
}

public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST: before");
    myStartService("action1");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    myStartService("action2");
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST: after");
}
```

**Service**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("action1")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TEST: received action1");
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals("action2")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "TEST: received action2");
    }
}
```

The problem is that this code first sleeps for 3000 milliseconds and only after that, `action1` and `action2` are received in the service.

You can clearly see what I am talking about if you take a look at this simple output (service receives action after `Thread.sleep()`):

```
2019-04-20 11:44:41.975 5599-5599/mypackage D/Activity: TEST: before
2019-04-20 11:44:44.980 5599-5599/mypackage D/Activity: TEST: after
2019-04-20 11:44:44.981 5599-5599/mypackage D/Service: TEST: received action1
2019-04-20 11:44:44.989 5599-5599/mypackage D/Service: TEST: received action2
```

And here is **expected** order of log outputs. How can I achieve it?

```
2019-04-20 11:44:41.975 5599-5599/mypackage D/Activity: TEST: before
2019-04-20 11:44:44.981 5599-5599/mypackage D/Service: TEST: received action1
2019-04-20 11:44:44.981 5599-5599/mypackage D/Service: TEST: received action2
2019-04-20 11:44:44.980 5599-5599/mypackage D/Activity: TEST: after
```

Comment: its because `onStartCommand` is called in the main UI thread that is blocked by yours `Thread.sleep` - for example use `Handler.postDelayed` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Thread.sleep`, use `Handler.postDelayed`

```
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST: before");
    myStartService("action1");
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myStartService("action2");
            Log.d(TAG, "TEST: after");
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```